# How to fix "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format" in this context?

Tags: c#, xaml

Sorry! Somewhat new to C# and having some trouble with my code. When I try to calculate vehicle price, it comes up with this error. I did do my own research, and I somewhat understand that the number I'm inputting isn't valid. I have tried full numbers and decimal numbers, the result is always the same. For this screenshot, I tried "5000". Any help is appreciated !

[Image of code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvFpv.png)

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const decimal GST_RATE = 0.1m;
    decimal subAmount;
    decimal gstAmount;
    decimal finalAmount;

    subAmount = decimal.Parse(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text) - 
        decimal.Parse(lessTradeInTextBox.Text);
    subAmountTextBlock.Text = subAmount.ToString("C");

    gstAmount = subAmount * GST_RATE;
    gstAmountTextBox.Text = gstAmount.ToString("C");

    finalAmount = subAmount + GST_RATE;
    finalAmountTextBox.Text = finalAmount.ToString("C");
}
```

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: try "ToString()". :)

Comment: @Classic_Fungus Thanks for the suggestion! Didn't work sadly :(

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If you mean what do I input to get the error. I've tried multiple numbers (Full numbers and one's with decimals). In the screenshot I provided, I tried 5000

Comment: You have **two** inputs in that calculation either of which could result in the error.  Which one was it? In large part use the `.TryParse` version when dealing with user input such as you appear to be.

Comment: Check if you getting any value in `vehiclePriceTextBox.Text` or `lessTradeInTextBox.Text`. Perform check on both input values first before attempting to parse them and use `TryParse`. Also place `try-catch` blocks to manage your exceptions in a graceful manner. `if(!string.IsNotNullOrEmpty(lessTradeInTextBox.Text)){//do your parsing}`